# How to setup iproute2 to share Internet connection from one interface (eth1) to another (eth0)?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iproute2

[image]

How can I give Internet access for Workstation ?

I already did on RPi:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
ip route add default via 192.168.8.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

But when I run  `ping -I enp6s0 8.8.8.8` from Workstation there is still `Destination Host Unreachable`. If I run `ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8` from RPi ping is working.

Comment: In general: Debug with `tcpdump -ni eth0` and `... eth1` in two windwos on the RaspPi to see what happens. In particular: check default action for FORWARD chain; check correct routing with `ip route get 8.8.8.8` on `Workstation`.

Comment: @dirkt I inspected ping request via `tcpdump -ni <eth0|eth1> icmp`, it's showing on eth0, `09:32:31.914721 IP 192.168.255.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 23549, seq 1, length 64`, but no output in eth1. `ip route get 8.8.8.8` output on Workstation is correct: `8.8.8.8 via 192.168.255.3 dev enp6s0  src 192.168.255.2 cache` . Maybe problem is `cache` ?

Comment: So you narrowed down the problem: The RaspPi is not forwarding/masqerading. Please edit question with output of `iptables -S`, and also do `ip route get 8.8.8.8` on the RaspPi, and also double check `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to see if it's really `1`.